# Maui Blazor No Hot Reload

Tags: visual-studio, maui-blazor

If I create a new Maui Blazor project using:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.4.0 Preview 2.1
```

When I run the app (windows machine) (index.blazor). I try to use hot reload by changing index.blazor to:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />


<style>
    h1{
        color:blue;
    }
</style>
```

I save the project but there is no hot reload.
However Hot Re4load is unavailable.
[image]

I read the docs and I made sure hot reload is enabled which it is.
Why wouldn't hot reload be unavailable?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to click the Hot Reload button or press Alt + F10 to reload? I have created a sample on the visual studio 17.4 preview 1.0 and test the hot reload with your code. When I clicked the Hot Reload button or pressed Alt + F10, the text color will changed.

In addition, in the official document, it also tells us:

> Apply the code changes using the Hot Reload button, or press ALT+F10.

For more information, you can check the [official document about update running code with hot reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload?view=vs-2022#update-running-code-with-hot-reload).

Comment: No it does not work either Alt F10 or clicking the Hot Reload icon. The icon at the top of the screen shows hot reload unavailable. I have no idea why.

Comment: I tested it on the VS 17.4 preview 1.0 and it worked. I updated the VS to the 17.4 preview 2.1 and met the same problem. So it seems a bug in the newest version. @PaulStanley

Comment: You can report it on the github. @PaulStanley

Answer (score 0):

Seems like HotReload for ASP.Net Core works a bit differently.

Accordingly to [microft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/hot-reload?view=aspnetcore-6.0) .NET CLI is the way to go.

Open command powershell and on solution folder type:

```
dotnet watch --project .\your-project-name-here.csproj
```

Or navigate the the project folder and just type: dotnet watch.